# Property getter as function

Tags: swift

Is it possible to access the getter of a property, so that it can be passed along to functions like `filter`/`map`/`reduce`?

For example, assuming I have a `User` entity:

```
struct User {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let isUnderaged: Bool

    func fullName() -> String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

let users: [User] = [] // or some computed result
```

If I need to filter all users that are underaged, then I need to create a temporary, anonymous, closure that only returns the `isUnderaged` value:

```
let underagedUsers = users.filter { $0.isUnderaged }
```

Similar, if I want to collect all the given names:

```
let givenNames = users.map { $0.firstName }
```

, I have to create another anonymous closure.

The `fullName()` method, on the other hand can be nicely passed along:

```
let allNames = users.map(User.fullName)
```

`#selector` accepts the `#selector(getter: User.isUnderaged)` form (`User` would need to be a class for this to work, just used it as example).

Does Swift supports something like this - passing getters to functions that allow closures?

Searching for something similar to this `users.filter(User.isUnderaged)` - this currently doesn't compile as `isUnderaged` cannot be accessed without an instance.

Comment: It's just a few more keystrokes. Come on, you can do them :)

Comment: In swift methods are the same types as closures, you can just assign them as you would any var (so without the () part) or pass them to a method as a parameter.

Comment: @kevin I'm discussing about properties, not methods. For methods see the `fullName()` example in the question.

Comment: And I'm saying there's no difference

Comment: @Sweeper actually for longer type names, the lambda has fewer characters :)

Comment: @kevin care to give an example of how to pass the property getter to map/filter?

Comment: It's right there in your own question. Your givenNames and allNames are functionally exactly the same thing, except one only gives you the first names. Do you have a specific use-case? Maybe add some real world code to showcase what the problem you're encountering is, it sounds like you're running into an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kevin: here's a simple use case: filter an array based on a property, without creating an anonymous closure. My question is if this is possible in Swift.

Comment: [Instance methods are curried functions](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) – but property accessors are not (as far as I know).

Comment: There’s was a pitch for allowing key paths to be promoted to getter closures: https://forums.swift.org/t/key-path-getter-promotion/11185/4

Comment: @MartinR yes, that's why `users.map(User.fullName)` work, unfortunately couldn't find a syntax to do this for property accessors

Comment: @Hamish thanks for the link, the solution exposed there sounds nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [Swift 5.2](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-2-released/), this is now possible, thanks to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md) Swift Evolution proposal.

Basically, key paths can now be used in places where functions are needed, like `map`/`filter`, etc.

For the example from the question, the usage would be along the lines of:

```swift
users.filter(\.isUnderaged)
users.map(\.firstName.count) // yes, chaining is also permitted
```